# Opencv 3.0 Broadcast data via Bluetooth

Tags: c++, opencv, bluetooth

I have developed a program in Opencv 3.0 with c++ api and it is working fine.

Now I want to broadcast some text data from my pc via Bluetooth.

Any Bluetooth c++ library that can be easily integrate with oepncv?

Please help 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are developing on Windows, you might be able to implement the Bluetooth communication via Windows Sockets (winsock). You can find a full working example at https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Bluetooth-Connection-e3263296#content . Other sollution is to create a C++/CLI interface and use some external library like 32feet (http://32feet.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks for replay.I am working on mac, please suggest if you have any idea of mac Bluetooth library.

Comment: Honestly I'm not really sure how you'd have to tackle this problem. The only way I can think of at the moment is to write your communication in Objective-C using "IOBluetooth.framework" and do some magic to make it work with your C++ application. Is it a console-based application?

Comment: yes it is console base application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt [Bluetooth](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-index.html) is an option, which supports osx, linux, ios, and android.